# Where can I get the names of keys in Blazor KeyboardEvents

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We try to do some things with Blazor KeaboardEventArgs and are struggeling with the key names. The documentation tells us:

> The key value of the key represented by the event. If the value has a printed representation, this attribute's value is the same as the char attribute. Otherwise, it's one of the key value strings specified in 'Key values'. If the key can't be identified, this is the string "Unidentified"

But **'Key Values'** is not specified any further.
Can anyone point to a (exhaustive) list of possible values for `KeyboardEventArgs.Key` and `KeyboardEventArgs.Code`?

Comment: **Exactly which** `KeyboardEventArgs` type are you referring to? Please specify the full type-name and namespace.

Comment: @Dai: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73419553/7149454

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are the names used by JavaScript.

Mozilla has [a list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

Comment: So there's no class with all the common ones as static properties?  I have to use the magic string `"Enter"` rather than some kind of `Keys.Enter`?

Comment: Just come across this and wondering the same thing. I've just made my own static class with all of the keyboard string mappings in there. Surprised there isn't just some Enum to choose from too. @PatrickSzalapski