# Does Blazor have an enum-typed equivalent of WinForms' Keys for KeyboardEventArgs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

.NET Core's [`KeyboardEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.keyboardeventargs?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class contains the `Key` and `Code` properties, which are both strings. So I must use magic strings like `if (e.Key == "Backspace") { }`.

.NET Framework (and the current Desktop API) have the [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) enum, which allows us to write code without magic strings, e.g. `if (e.Key == Keys.Back) { }`.

Is there an equivalent enum for .NET Core? I want this for a Blazor app.

Comment: Are you after a cross-platform solution, or is Windows-only okay?

Comment: @Dai, No it needs to be aspnet.core (for blazor). I don't want to depend on the framework or windows/forms. I could recreate it myself, but I hope not.

Comment: Interessting... [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68861324/2441442)

Comment: I just noticed you're referring to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs` - the reason it doesn't have any enum members is because it represents the DOM's `KeyboardEvent`, which also uses only string values (the `number`-based values vary between browsers and so can't be relied-upon in modern JS). As C# `enum` types are strictly integer-based (and not `String`-based) what you're after simply isn't possible without building your own key-to-enum map, which would require hundreds of entries.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Noooo! So we're stuck with magic strings... If you add that as an answer I'll close.

Comment: @Dai That makes sense. If you add that as an answer (basically, it can't be done), I'll close. Thanks.

Comment: You say that you don't want to rely on WinForms but that's exactly what you would be doing if you used that enum in a .NET Framework application. You ask whether there's an equivalent for .NET Core but it seems like the actual question you want answered is whether there's an equivalent for ASP.NET, in which case the answer is "no". Those properties of `KeyboardEventArgs` are type `string` for a reason.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think there's a miscommunication here - I know I would have to rely on winforms stuff if I used it... and I don't want to do that :-) Thanks for confirming that the answer is "no". I will continue to use magic strings and just ensure my tests cover these cases.

Comment: @Ionix I have not much expertise in Blazor to make an definitive answer, but as it seems, the key events seems to be specified by Javascript. If thats true, we could create our own static class from the specification. Realy strange there seems no `JsSpecificationKeyType` by default in the Blazor Framework (Same as many other Features Like LocalStorage). Probably because it's relative young.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yep I just created a limited enum with just those values that matter to me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *"I think there's a miscommunication here"*. Yes, there was, and I explained what it was. You asked if there is an equivalent of `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` for .NET Core and that is `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`. What you actually wanted to know was whether there is an equivalent for ASP.NET - maybe ASP.NET Core specifically - which there isn't. It's important to understand the difference between the language, the technology and the framework so you know which your issue relates to. You were asking a framework question when your issue related to technology.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Look at the [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#applies-to) which show that it is part of Framework and WindowsDesktop, not Core. Regardless, this is pedantry, anyone would understand my point, and yours.

Comment: Look at the documentation page you linked to in the first place. It's part of ASP.NET Core. not .NET Core as you said. You're asking for something specific to ASP.NET Core. Windows Desktop and ASP.NET Core are as .NET Core as each other, no more and no less. I didn't understand your point to begin with and apparently neither did Dai. I'm just trying to help you avoid making similar mistakes in future so that you'll get the help you want a soon as is possible. I can't make you recognise the error but I can walk away knowing I've done all I can.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think we're unnecessarily splitting hairs. That enum is unsuitable for aspnet/blazor. I appreciate your willingness to help... good on ya' mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `KeyboardEventArgs` you're referring to is Blazor's own `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs` which is the Blazor view of the DOM's [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

While the DOM's `KeyboardEvent` *does* have integer (`number` in JS)-typed members, these are all either obsolete, non-standard or only ever seen in draft specs, and/or have values that vary between browsers and/or OS families, which makes them non-portable and so it's no surprise that Blazor doesn't use them.

---

Of the myriad proprietary and draft members of `KeyboardEvent` DOM interface, only `code` and `key` are still defined in the current [draft DOM UI Events specification](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboardevents) and [draft DOM Level 3 Events specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboardevents), all other key/char-indicator members are obsolete. I've made this table to list those members:

| `KeyboardEvent` property | Type | Printable | Nonprintable | Status | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `char` | `string` | **True** | False | **Obsolete** |  |
| `charCode` | `number` | **True** | False | **Obsolete** | Only used in `keypress` event (not `keydown`, etc). Returns ambiguous results in many cases. |
| `code` | `string` | **True** | **True** | [Current](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboardevents) |  |
| `key` | `string` | **True** | **True** | [Current](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboardevents) |  |
| `keyIdentifier` | `string` | **True** | **True** | **Obsolete** | Proprietary to Apple Safari/WebKit. |
| `keyCode` | `number` | False | **True** | **Obsolete** |  |
| `which` | `number` | **True** | **True** | **Obsolete** | Inherited from `UIEvent`. Aliases `charCode` for printable chars, or `keyCode` for nonprintable chars. |

Consider that C#'s `enum`-types are all integer-based: as of C# 11 in 2022 there is no concept of a `String`-based `enum` type which, which means if you (or the Blazor dev team) *did* want an `enum`-based member of Blazor's `KeyboardEventArgs` then you (or they) would have to manually maintain a mapping between `KeyboardEvent.code/key` string values and their enum members, which would be a huge PITA to maintain, especially given that as of October 2022 the DOM UI Events spec is still in the draft stage.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks Dai!